# Can a looped Android be rooted?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, adb, root-access, side-loading

I deleted a system file from my Android (com.android.providers.settings.apk) and now my Android is in a loop. It is a KitKat tablet and I am able to use adb sideload.
Is there a way to root the tablet in these conditions?

Comment: Can you tell why do you want to root "in such conditions"? Shouldn't you be trying to recover than to root this device? Anyhow, which tablet is this?

Comment: I can't fathom what kind of loop is this? Is this loop some error (in loop) in Android, or a bootloop?

Comment: can you tell us what is the tablet model

Comment: nJoy HECTOR 8
MTK 8382,Quad-Core,1.3 GHz, MediaTek
njoy.ro/tablets/hector8#specificatii

Comment: The tablet is nJoy HECTOR 8.
MTK 8382,Quad-Core,1.3 GHz, MediaTek, 1GB RAM.
link here : njoy.ro/tablets/hector8#specificatii                                                     It has a bootloop and because I do not have a rom to install, I was thinking to try to root it, because maybe after I will able to connect to it and pushing, somehow, the deleted package (com.android.providers.settings.apk)  and so it'll root without installing a firmware I do not have anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom recovery, chances are you're already rooted. Try typing "whoami", and in case it returns "root", you have root access.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a custom recovery. I wiped cache and try to reinstall without success and I lost the root that moment.

Comment: I also try to look for a rom but because it is a budget tablet it seems that only the seller has the firmware and not willingly to give it to me. I can only go and pay for a fully resoft but I am not going to receive the rom from them.